# Should I merge master to a shared stable integration branch before rebase?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

Our team seems to be running into this problem over and over again. When we start on a project we create an integration branch from the `master` and call it `stable`. Now, each individual developer branches out from `stable` and once they are done, they create a pull request to the `stable` and do a squash and merge before closing it.

The problem happens when we want to `merge` `stable` back to `master`. We usually `rebase` on top of `master` but this leads to many conflicts since 2 months down the line `master` has a lot more commits  than when we branched from.

I read some posts like - [Git Workflows: Rebasing Published/Shared Branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611581/git-workflows-rebasing-published-shared-branches) and some of them seem to advocate merging `master` to `stable` from time to time before doing the final `rebase` of `stable` on top of `master` at the time of creating a pull request and then there was one [What is the right git workflow with shared feature branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927566/what-is-the-right-git-workflow-with-shared-feature-branches) which said that back merge from `master` to `stable` is a bad idea.

My question is - Is merging `master` to `stable` from time-to-time the ideal solution here to prevent the `rebase` conflict hell which we go through every time or are there any better solutions out there? If this was already answered please let me know.

We can't `merge` `stable` to `master` sooner because `master` requires the latest and greatest end-to-end functional production ready code.

Comment: Who is merging to `master` in those 2 months? Do you have multiple `stable`-like branches?

Comment: @Maaz Syed Adeeb `master` is like the central branch in which devs from different teams continuously merge their work. We only have 1 `stable`. Even if we do have multiple we'd still have to integrate all of them and check before being able to merge to `master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is merging master to stable from time-to-time the ideal solution here to prevent the rebase conflict hell which we go through every time or are there any better solutions out there?

In your particular workflow, where master is actively modified while stable is updated... yes, even though it is not a best practice.

Ideally, master should *not* evolve much while your integration branch (stable) is updated.
An example of such workflow: [gitworkflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53405887/6309), which uses a "next" branch as integration, but will then remerge the feature branch themselves directly to master (which has not change much since the last release)